# SQL: Заполнить пустые строки значениями из последней непустой строки

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Я пытаюсь задать запрос который брал бы таблицу1 и выводил все значения из неё, только при этом все значения NULL заменялись бы последним значением не NULL.

Мне необходимо использовать JOIN. Создав две таблицы (дубликат таблицы1).

Из оригинальной таблицы я хотел бы взять значение и присваивать их в вторую таблицу в те места где в дубликате есть NULL.

| Date | Num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | Null |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 11 |
| 5 | 19 |
| 6 | Null |
| 7 | Null |

Вот так должен выглядеть результат:

| Date | Num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 11 |
| 5 | 19 |
| 6 | 19 |
| 7 | 19 |

Все поиск пришли к результату ниже, правда есть, но можно ли это как то использовать без оконной функции? Мне кажется можно как то с помощью трех подзапросов решить данную проблему правда не понимаю как.

```
select
  a.date,
  case when a.num is not null
    then (select @num := a.num)
    else (select @num := @num)
  end new_num
from
(select @num := num, min(date) from tst) m,
tst a
join tst b on a.date <= b.date
group by a.date, a.num;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.`Date`, 
       COALESCE( t1.Num, ( SELECT t2.Num
                           FROM test t2
                           WHERE t1.`Date` >= t2.`Date`
                             AND t2.Num IS NOT NULL
                           ORDER BY t2.`Date` DESC LIMIT 1 )) Num
FROM test t1
```

Comment: Мне необходимо использовать JOIN.!!! Это обязательное условие

Comment: Ааа.. так это не по делу, а домашняя работа? используйте, я не против. Подзапрос есть, просто переместите его во FROM как LATERAL.